# Which arguments exist to pass to an exe (start-process -path ... -ArgumentList)

Tags: powershell, automation, executable

The goal:
Coworkers should be able to install a software by one-click via PowerShell

The issue:
I am not aware how to automate the installation of a software, e.g. the executable.
This is my code:

start-process -Verb runAs -wait '.......\setup.exe'  -ArgumentList

My question:
I couldn't find any valid values for the "-ArgumentList"? How do I tell PowerShell which Options (Radio buttons) to press when running the installation in the background? Is there a standard of valid arguments, or how do I find out which ones are valid for the specific exe?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: That depends 100% on the installer - one installer might take a different set of command line options than another - you need to inspect the documentation (or perhaps try inspecting the installer itself with `setup.exe /?` or `setup.exe --help` or similar).

Comment: You would need to provide all of the information about the specific software, version and installer package type. If you're not looking for a specific solution for a particular installer ytour question is too broad to answer.

Comment: I've created auto installers for SCCM for our company for a few years now. Best place to start is learning about the types of installers: http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php. Some autoinstallers allow you to create an 'answer file' - others essentially force you to take the defaults. You will likely have to guess which installer it is and try the various flags from the link until something works.